# Output values found in cursor to logcat? - Android

Tags: android, database, android-cursor

I'm trying to debug an issue myself.  May post it later if I fail ;-)

My logcat log states `"android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2"`

I would like to use `log.v("desc", cursor)` to show what the cursor returns.  Is there a way to specify a value from it like cursor[0] ?

Comment: "I would like to use log.v("desc", cursor) to show what the cursor returns. Is there a way to specify a value from it like cursor[0] ?"

I wonder what you mean in the sentence? Would you like to see whole row number 0 (value of all columns in row 0)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `moveToFirst()` on Cursor.

Answer (score 70):

Android has provided a specific class just for debugging Cursors. It is called [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html).

Call the method [dumpCursorToString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursorToString%28android.database.Cursor%29) to view the contents of your cursor.

This helper loops through and prints out the content of the Cursor for you, and returns the cursor to its original position so that it doesn't mess up your iterating logic.

Answer (score 64):

use this before `cursor.moveToFirst()`

```
Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor))
```

Comment: + import android.database.DatabaseUtils;

Answer (score 13):

If you intend to write contents of the cursor to the logcat row by row you can use code as below:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int columnsQty = cursor.getColumnCount();
        for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
            sb.append(cursor.getString(idx));
            if (idx < columnsQty - 1)
                sb.append("; ");
        }
        Log.v(TAG, String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", cursor.getPosition(), 
            sb.toString()));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: what if column is not string, it may be int double?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're looking for where the cursor is at a specific point in time, call `Cursor.getPosition()`

Take a look at the [Cursor API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).

It's often very wordy, but sometimes it helps.